# how to group, summarize and render table in shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

Im trying to create a summarized table that can be rendered in a local shiny web app.

Here is a sample dataset.

```
df1 = structure(list(D_NoIDProv = c("900098550", "900098550", "900098550", 
"900098550", "900098550", "900098550", "900098550", "900098550", 
"900098550", "900098550", "900098550", "900098550", "900098550", 
"900098550", "900098550", "900098550", "900098550", "900098550", 
"900098550", "900098550"), D_TipoTec = c("N", "N", "N", "N", 
"N", "N", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
"M", "M", "M"), CUMS = c("150416", "150416", "150416", "170176", 
"170176", "170176", "19945455-02", "19945455-02", "20046741-04", 
"20046741-04", "20041735-05", "20041735-05", "20041735-05", "20041735-05", 
"20001982-02", "20001982-02", "20001982-02", "19933626-02", "19933626-02", 
"19933626-02"), D_CantTotAEntregar = c(2, 2, 1, 30, 30, 30, 1, 
1, 90, 90, 30, 30, 30, 30, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), D_FecDireccionamiento = structure(c(1617299520, 
1617299520, 1617299580, 1617299640, 1617299700, 1617299700, 1617235200, 
1617235260, 1617235500, 1617235560, 1617357540, 1617357600, 1617357600, 
1617357660, 1617358080, 1617358080, 1617358080, 1617358200, 1617358200, 
1617358260), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), 
    D_FecMaxEnt = structure(c(18747, 18777, 18808, 18747, 18777, 
    18808, 18854, 18885, 18748, 18779, 18748, 18779, 18809, 18840, 
    18748, 18779, 18809, 18748, 18779, 18809), class = "Date"), 
    ValorUnitarioMax = c(75952, 75952, 75952, 18594, 18594, 18594, 
    96725, 96725, 156, 156, 897, 897, 897, 897, 32695, 32695, 
    32695, 20892, 20892, 20892), ValorTotal = c(151904, 151904, 
    75952, 557810, 557810, 557810, 96725, 96725, 14067, 14067, 
    26903, 26903, 26903, 26903, 32695, 32695, 32695, 20892, 20892, 
    20892)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

my server code so far

```
      df1 = df1 %>%  
            group_by(D_NoIDProv) %>% 
            summarise(SumValorTotal=sum(ValorTotal)) %>%
            ungroup()

    output$mytable = DT::renderDataTable( df1 ,
                                          filter = 'top',
                                          rownames = FALSE,
                                          options = list(autoWidth = TRUE,
                                                         columnDefs = list(list(width = '100px',className = 'dt-center' ,targets = 0:2),
                                                                           list(width = '400px',className = 'dt-center' ,targets = 3))
                                                         )
                                          )
```

this works well in RStudio but im having trouble trying to visualize the summarized table on shiny since it just wont populate.

I ran some checks and the table is correctly rendered before the :

```
        group_by(D_NoIDProv) %>% 
        summarise(SumValorTotal=sum(ValorTotal)) %>%
        ungroup()
```

am i doing something wrong?

will appreciate your help

Comment: if `D_NoIDProv` is a variable in the data, why not just do `group_by(D_NoIDProv)` instead of the indirection of `!!sym(.)` (which isn't working for you anyway).

Comment: Fyi, objects not found, so it's not possible to test or reproduce this: `date_start`, `date_end`, `precios_unitarios_mipres`, and I'm assuming that `D_CantTotAEntregar` and `ValorUnitarioMax` are found in `precios_unitarios_mipres`, otherwise please provide them as well.

Comment: sorry about the `!!sym(.)`. that was a test i was doing with no good results. i edited the question

Comment: Please keep [edit]ing :-) You still have one `!!sym(.)`, and we still don't know what the other 3 (or more) objects look like.

Comment: done. sorry about that.

Comment: (1/2) A few things about making the problem *reproducible*. I recognize that you are providing sample data (great, thank you!) and using `dput` (again great, ty!). And replacing the `date_*` variables is a good start, recognizing that shiny's `input$` is in play here. I don't think the question here needs to care about the dates, though, since your sample data only has two rows. However ... the data to join does not produce any matches: `df$D_CodSerTecAEntregar %in% precios_unitarios_mipres$CUMS` is all false.

Comment: let me get a bigger dataset right away

Comment: (2/2) I can easily change one of the joining variables so that we actually get a `sum`, which is fine. After that, I replaced your `DT::render*` with `DT::datatable` just to attempt it on the console, and I get `DataTables warning: table id=DataTables_Table_0 - Requested unknown parameter '2' for row 0, column 2. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4`. The output frame only has two columns, so changing to a single `columnDefs = list(list(width = '100px',className = 'dt-center' ,targets = 0:1)` fixes the error. Is that what you're after?

Comment: That is, your frame is 2 columns, but your options use `targets=0:2` (which needs 3 columns) and `targets=3` (which presumes at least 4 columns).

Comment: i have edited the question with a more reproducible example and dataset

Comment: So we're still in the position where you are providing options for columns not present in your data. Are you expecting 4 or more columns after your `summarize`? Said differently, the `summarize` (grouping on one variable and producing one variable) will *by default* have only two columns. What columns are you expecting to be retained? (We can keep more, but you need to be explicit about it.)

Comment: @r2evans thanks so much for pointing that error. i was looking in the wrong direction and blaming it on the group_by. i have fixed id per your advise on the columndefs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not with the `group_by` or with the basic rendering, it's that your options to `DT::datatable` are suggesting more columns than your summarization is producing. Notable, `df1` has only two columns (`D_NoIDProv` and `SumValorTotal`), but with `targets=0:2` and `targets=3` in your options, you are suggesting that you have at least 4 columns.

If you are expecting only two columns, then you need to reduce your options to be just:

```r
df1 %>%  
  group_by(D_NoIDProv) %>% 
  summarise(SumValorTotal=sum(ValorTotal)) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  DT::datatable(filter = 'top',
                rownames = FALSE,
                options = list(autoWidth = TRUE,
                  columnDefs = list(list(width = '100px',className = 'dt-center' ,targets = 0:1))
                )
  )
```

[image: both columns 100px]

or

```r
df1 %>%  
  group_by(D_NoIDProv) %>% 
  summarise(SumValorTotal=sum(ValorTotal)) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  DT::datatable(filter = 'top',
                rownames = FALSE,
                options = list(autoWidth = TRUE,
                  columnDefs = list(list(width = '100px',className = 'dt-center' ,targets = 0),
                                    list(width = '400px',className = 'dt-center' ,targets = 1))
                )
  )
```

[image: different column widths]